# Creating a new href attribute using getAttribute & innerText with Javascript

Tags: javascript, href, getattribute

I've got a list of products and what i want to do is to make the price of the product clickable just like the product title linking to the same product URL.

I've created a for loop to try and do this, but the issue i have is each href link for each product is being created per product where i only need the one price with the corresponding href link. How do i correct this?

Note: I don't have access to change the original html which is why i'm trying to make these changes in javascript

```js
var getAllLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.productTitle').forEach(function(el){
    var createNewLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.productPrice').forEach(function (elem){
  elem.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<a href=" + el.getAttribute('href') + ">"+ elem.innerText +"</a>");
  })    
});
```

```css
.container {padding-bottom: 20px;}
```

```html
<article class="container" data-ga-product="04245">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product1">Product 1</a>
    <div class="productPriceContainer">
      <div class="productPrimary">
        <span class="productPrice">€&nbsp;5,90</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="container" data-ga-product="05395">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product2">Product 2</a>
    <div class="productPriceContainer">
      <div class="productPrimary">
        <span class="productPrice">€&nbsp;145,90</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="container" data-ga-product="263743">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product3">Product 3</a>
    <div class="productPriceContainer">
      <div class="productPrimary">
        <span class="productPrice">€&nbsp;35,90</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="container" data-ga-product="60493">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product4">Product 4</a>
    <div class="productPriceContainer">
      <div class="productPrimary">
        <span class="productPrice">€&nbsp;125,90</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about your problem but I think maybe this is what you want. 
Please let me know if I got it wrong :)

```js
var getLink = document.querySelectorAll('.productTitle');
var newLink = document.querySelectorAll('.productPrice');

getLink.forEach((link, i) => {
  newLink[i].insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<a href=" + link.getAttribute('href') + ">" + newLink[i].innerText + "</a>");
  newLink[i].remove();
});
```

```css
.container {padding-bottom: 20px;}
```

```html
<article class="container" data-ga-product="04245">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product1">Product 1</a>
    <div class="productPriceContainer">
      <div class="productPrimary">
        <span class="productPrice">€&nbsp;5,90</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="container" data-ga-product="05395">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product2">Product 2</a>
    <div class="productPriceContainer">
      <div class="productPrimary">
        <span class="productPrice">€&nbsp;145,90</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="container" data-ga-product="263743">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product3">Product 3</a>
    <div class="productPriceContainer">
      <div class="productPrimary">
        <span class="productPrice">€&nbsp;35,90</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="container" data-ga-product="60493">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product4">Product 4</a>
    <div class="productPriceContainer">
      <div class="productPrimary">
        <span class="productPrice">€&nbsp;125,90</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just include the price within the `a` tag and forget about JavaScript all together?

```
<article class="container" data-ga-product="04245">
  <div class="productContent">
    <a class="productTitle" href="#product1">Product 1
      <span class="productPriceContainer">
        <span class="productPrimary">
          <span class="productPrice">€&nbsp;5,90</span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
</article>
```

You'd need to change the inner `div`s to `span`s to be semantic HTML, and potentially some CSS changes to get the styling just right, but this seems like a way better solution.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have access to change any of the html which is why i'm having to do it in javascript. Maybe I should have said this in my question